# How to remove a stored user account in ADB?

Tags: adb, account

I am looking for a solution with which it is possible to remove a stored user account (Settings -> Users & Account) via adb. Has anyone of you already done that?

Answer (score 5):

**Case for applications accounts:**

You need to have root privileges to do it. The accounts are stored in the database `/data/system_ce/0/accounts_ce.db` which need root privileges to access it.

In case you have a rooted phone, you can simply delete the concerned entry and it'll be removed.

**Case for System users**

To delete a system user, you can start by listing the existing ones:

```
pm list users
```

Each user entry is as follow : `UserInfo{ID:USERNAME:INT}`

To delete a user, you can use the command:

```
pm remove-user ID
```

Where ID is the ID of the user (result of the previous command)

Comment: Thank you, i found it. I deleted the users from the database, but will the change be automatically adopted? I can still see the deleted users in the settings.

Comment: Did you try to reboot after deleting the users from the database?

Comment: hi @St0rm, You are right the account would be removed after reboot.

Comment: How to refresh account with reboot? do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

if you have no root, use this

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 999 com.google.android.gms
```