# Delete Accounts in Accounts & Backup Settings Android 9 with ADB nonrot

Tags: android, adb

I want to remove my Facebook or tiktok account from Accounts & Backup in Settings without removing the app.
I used this command:
`adb shell pm clear com.facebook.katana` - but it only deletes application data, not the account saved in Accounts & backup in Settings.
`adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.facebook.katana` - It completely deletes and uninstalls that app, Do not restart the machine 
Please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448483/how-to-remove-a-stored-user-account-in-adb

Comment: @Robert. That answer does not apply. Those are the commands I tried but failed

Comment: Don't you think that it would be a good idea to edit your question and include the commands you have executed and the error output you got? Just saying "failed" is a little bit short, may be you simply made a mistake executing the commands?

Comment: @Robert . the above two commands both work, but not for my purpose

Comment: I was talking about the commands in the linked (see link in my first comment) question/answer.